# Requesting camera permissions from within a View

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have a customized Android `SurfaceView` that I'm using to display the video stream of a camera. In order to access the camera I need to obtain the corresponding permissions from the user.

The Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) explains how this is done using the methods `checkSelfPermission`, `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` and
`requestPermissions`.

Now, what I would like to do is to request permissions directly from within the customized View (please don't attempt to educate me that this is bad practice, etc.).

The reason why I fail to achieve this is that there seems to be no way to tell Android where to find the `ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`callback. It seems that Android automatically expects it to be part of the `Activity` or `Fragment` that hosts my modified view.

I miss a `<whatever>.setCallback(this)` call I could add to my custom view code after implementing `ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` directly on the view.

Is there really no non-hacky-looking way to request permissions from within an Android View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that Android automatically expects it to be part of the Activity or Fragment that hosts my modified view

Correct.

> Is there really no non-hacky-looking way to request permissions from within an Android View?

Correct.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'm depending on the `surfaceCreated` and `surfaceDestroyed` methods of `SurfaceView` to start and stop the camera video stream. From outside of the view I don't know when these methods run which means that I need to request permissions before the view is even created.

Answer (score 1):

Put the onPermissionResult method in the activity/fragment which calls it and create a public method inside the view “proceedAfterPermission” and call it from the parent activity/fragment.

And for asking permission from view you can pass the context from the activity/fragment to the view, just make the Context variable public.

Comment: I would still have to implement `ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` on the Activity/Fragment even if I call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)getContext()...` from within the `SurfaceView` and hence cannot properly abstract everything away in the `SurfaceView`.

Comment: Yes you have to implement onRequestPermission result in the activity/fragment but after when you receive the callback just call any public method to notify the view about the callback. There is no other way bro I’m sorry :(

Comment: Yes, just another Android flaw (no offense intended). Thanks anyway for your answer, welcome on StackOverflow.